# How to print out the name of a variable

Tags: python, opencv

in the following code snippet:

```
import cv2
for color_space in (cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV,
                    cv2.COLOR_RGB2LUV,
                    cv2.COLOR_RGB2HLS,
                    cv2.COLOR_RGB2YUV,
                    cv2.COLOR_RGB2YCrCb):   
    *print_it_as_name(color_space)*
```

With which real statement can I replace `print_it_as_name` such that the output is

> cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV
>   cv2.COLOR_RGB2LUV
>   cv2.COLOR_RGB2HLS
>   cv2.COLOR_RGB2YUV,
>   cv2.COLOR_RGB2YCrCb

Without hardcoding it using if statements?

Comment: Just enclose it in quotation marks `''`? If you want to work with variables dynamically you can always use their names as strings and obtain the corresponding values via `getattr`.

Comment: But I can't help feeling there's a deeper problem here, to which the usual answer is "use a dict".

Comment: Exactly, I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've come up with a little hack to work this out using eval:

```
for color_space in ("cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV",
                    "cv2.COLOR_RGB2LUV",
                    "cv2.COLOR_RGB2HLS",
                    "cv2.COLOR_RGB2YUV",
                    "cv2.COLOR_RGB2YCrCb"):   
    print(color_space) # prints the name of the variable
    print(eval(color_space)) # prints the actual value of the variable.
```

Probably not good practice to actually do this, I would recommend the dictionary approach but since you asked for it this way this is how its done.

Comment: My bad: I didnt give you the whole problem in my first post. Please see the edit.

Comment: Ah sorry for canging the rules of the game again: But I wouldnt bother, if I did not want to use the actual statements cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV... later in the code. So I really want to iterate over these. Is there no reflection module in python?

Comment: @user1934212 sorry but I have no idea ^^

Comment: @MukeshIngham This is no good use case for `eval`, you should use `getattr` instead.

Answer (score 3):

As others suggested, use a dict.

```
import cv2
data = { 'cv2.'+att : getattr(cv2, att)
         for att in ('COLOR_RGB2HSV','COLOR_RGB2LUV',...) }
print(data.keys())
```

If you need all the `COLOR_*` attributes, you can avoid the hard coded list:

```
data = { ... for att in dir(cv2) if att.startswith('COLOR_') }
```

Comment: Thanks, but that really is not the point. I want to iterate over these values and uses these values later in the code, but also print the name of these values out.

Comment: @user1934212 I see. See my other answer then.

Answer (score 3):

Use a reverse-map, mapping from the value, to its original name (assuming values are unique).

```
import cv2
reverse_map = { v:k for k,v in dir(cv2) if k.startswith('COLOR_') }
for color_space in (cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV,
                    cv2.COLOR_RGB2LUV,
                    cv2.COLOR_RGB2HLS,
                    cv2.COLOR_RGB2YUV,
                    cv2.COLOR_RGB2YCrCb):   
    print(reverse_map[color_space])
```